# What does "noch" mean in "hatte noch bei ihm gelernt"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I have been looking at Duden's entry for *noch*, but I can't ascertain what it means in the following subheading:

> Fritz Liebsch hatte **noch** bei August Horch gelernt – nach dem Krieg baute er Traktoren statt edler Karossen.

Can it be translated into English in this case, or can it not be conveyed?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate what you already know and understood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Noch** in this sentence means the action done was not possible anymore a while later.

> Fritz Liebsch hatte **(noch)** bei August Horch gelernt.

*Fritz Liebsch had learned from August Horch **(when he was still taking apprentices)**.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the meaning of the word “noch” in your sentence is [1.a.](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/noch_nun_bis_jetzt_viel). I would translate it as “still” in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't. I would vote for 3c: "drückt aus, dass ein bestimmtes Geschehen, ein Umstand einige Zeit später nicht mehr möglich [gewesen] wäre" (because currently, you can't be taught by August Horch anymore). There is no direct English equivalent.